# Prestashop smarty make a form for user and save the input fields to the database?

Tags: module, smarty, prestashop

In Prestashop I am doing a module. In that module I have view file(smarty template). In smarty I am doing form so that user can submit the form from frontend. Now when user makes fill the form and clicks on submit then the form should save all the vales to thae database. So for that in smarty I made a form like this

```
<div id="content" class="form-wrapper" >
  <div class="form-content">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" /> <br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/> <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"/> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit-query" id="submit-enquiry" value="submit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and in the file where the values will be submitted I have made my code like this

```
<?php
include '../../../config/settings.inc.php';
include '../../../config/defines.inc.php';
include '../../../config/config.inc.php';
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../init.php');


if(Tools::getValue('submit-query')) {
  $this->_html .=$this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated successfully'));
}
  else {
    $this->_html .= $this->displayError($this->l('You Have Some Errors'));
  }
?>
```

Now when doing click on my submit button It is showing error like this

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in file.php on line 11
```

Now can someone kindly tell me what is the issue here and how can I make a form in smarty for frontend users so that they can submit the form and the value will be stored to the database. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Information is clear enough. $this can be used only inside class and in this file you use this outside a class and this won't work. Probably _html is property of some class or you need to access view in some other way. I don't know Prestashop so I cannot help you

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Do you find any solution ?

Comment: @navid I'm not the author of this question. You should ask NewUser :)

Comment: @NewUser Do you find any solution ?  you're right MarcinNabialek :)

Comment: @navid yes I got the solution.I just saved the value of smarty form into the database using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend to do the processing inside of your module, e.g. in `init()` function, you can get your module link using `$this->context->link->getModuleLink('myModuleName');` and add it to the form action attribute, all variables can be assigned using `$this->context->smarty->assign()`.

Storing values in database is quite a wide question. You have to provide some more details about it.

Check some tutorials from Prestashop e.g. [Creating a Prestashop Module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module). You will find most of your answers there.